# Date Accessed Field Not Updating WIndows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, metadata

I've added the "Date Accessed" field to windows file explorer, however, it is not updating when opening media files (pictures, videos, etc.) I've edited the "ntfsDisableLastAccess" registry key to "0x80000000" and have tried running the command "fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0" and rebooting but nothing seems to work.

It's worth mentioning that the drive i'm accessing is a external hard disk.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!